# update list element and combined with list

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I am trying this in C#.

| ID | ENTITY_NAME | ENTITY_VALUE | SECTION_GROUP | DOC_ID | GROUP_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dNumber | U220059090 | GROUP 1 | 40 | 0 |
| 2 | tDate | 6-Dec-22 | GROUP 1 | 40 | 0 |
| 3 | dNumber | U220059090 | GROUP 2 | 40 | 0 |
| 4 | tDate | 6-Dec-22 | GROUP 2 | 40 | 0 |
| 5 | sCompany | bp |  | 40 | 0 |

The one with Section_group blank should get merge into both grouped result and Group_Id column should get updated with incremental value.

I am looking to get as below.

```
    ENTITY_NAME   ENTITY_VALUE SECTION_GROUP  DOC_ID      GROUP_ID
        dNumber     U220059090       GROUP 1      40     1
          tDate       6-Dec-22       GROUP 1      40     1
        sCompany            bp                    40     1

        dNumber     U220059090       GROUP 2      40     2
          tDate       6-Dec-22       GROUP 2      40     2
        sCompany            bp                    40     2
```

I created two list. first list where section_group is not null and second list where section_Group is null and applied grouping on section_group for first list.

```
var itemSectionGroup = item.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Sectiongroup));
var itemSectionGroupNull = item.Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Sectiongroup)).ToList();
var group = itemSectionGroup.GroupBy(x => new { x.Sectiongroup });
int grp_num = 1;

foreach (var grp in group)
        {
            List<ParserRequestEntityLog> newList = itemSectionGroupNull.GetRange(0,itemSectionGroupNull.Count);
            grp.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Groupid = grp_num);
            newList.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Groupid = grp_num);
            resultList.AddRange(grp.ToList());
            resultList.AddRange(newList);
            grp_num += 1;
      }
```

with this code the Group_Id is getting overridden because of reference type. what I am getting is below which is wrong.

```
    ENTITY_NAME   ENTITY_VALUE SECTION_GROUP  DOC_ID      GROUP_ID
        dNumber     U220059090       GROUP 1      40     1
          tDate       6-Dec-22       GROUP 1      40     1
        sCompany            bp                    40     2 <= this is getting overridden. 

        dNumber     U220059090       GROUP 2      40     2
          tDate       6-Dec-22       GROUP 2      40     2
        sCompany            bp                    40     2
```

I looking to do this correct and efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way is Serialize and Deserialize it back to avoid reference:

`var cloneGroupNull = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Test>>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(itemSectionGroupNull));`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `AsNoTracking()` method to avoid it getting overridden. Here is working demo, Hope it can give you some help:

**Model**

```
public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ENTITY_NAME { get; set; }
        public string ENTITY_VALUE { get; set; }
        public string? SECTION_GROUP { get; set; }
        public int DOC_ID { get; set; }
        public int GROUP_ID { get; set; }
    }
```

**linq**

```
var itemSectionGroup = _dbcontext.item.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.SECTION_GROUP));

           
var resultList = new List<Item>();          

var result =  itemSectionGroup.GroupBy(x => x.SECTION_GROUP).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < result.Count(); i++)
    {
        var session1 = itemSectionGroup.Where(x => x.SECTION_GROUP == result[i]).ToList();
        var Nullsession = _dbcontext.item.Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.SECTION_GROUP)).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
        session1.Add(Nullsession);
        session1.ForEach(x => x.GROUP_ID = (i + 1));
        resultList.AddRange(session1);
                
    };
```

Demo:

[image]